# RAID 1 array not appearing in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, raid

I've got a new setup with a RAID 1 array for data and other bits and pieces, using [this card](https://www.ebay.com/itm/IBM-M1015-9220-8I-6GB-SAS2-SATA3-PCI-e-RAID-Controller-Card-8087-to-sata-9211-8/192928587871). The motherboard is MSI MPG Z390. I've been fiddling with the system for a week or so now, and the RAID is OK with Windows, showing up in two separate installs. After installing Windows, all the partitions on the array were visible (in both installations), but there were a couple of occasions right at the beginning when the partitions disappeared completely from the system. That stressed me out, of course, at the time, but then I realised that after rebooting everything was still there and fine. It's a bit of a concern but not the main reason that I'm here of course.

I installed Ubuntu 20 on Friday night, and unfortunately none of the partitions in the RAID array are appearing automatically. Just to clarify - Windows isn't controlling this array in any way as far as I know, unless it's done something without my knowledge. The RAID is also not visible when I boot from a GParted USB. What do I do about this? I haven't found a great deal of information from searching so far.

Thanks in advance :~)

Comment: That particular card works out of the box with most Linux distros. To show disks in RAID arrays you have to load the generic sg SCSI driver: `modprobe sg`

Comment: OK, and then where would I find them? I don't see anything in the file explorer.

Comment: (and thanks for replying, of course)